# Site Analytics not showing a pop up for Traffic diagram and pop up position is to far to the right

Tags: feature-request, bug, site-analytics

**Bug:**

Votes, pop up shows as expected:

[image]

Traffic, no pop up:

[image]

Normally the div with `class="events-tooltip"` gets the style `display: block;` on mouseover on a point in the diagram and then `display: none;` on mouseout. For Traffic nothing happens.

To replicate:

Sometimes it happens on page load, even when using `Empty Cache and Hard Reload` in `Chrome`.

I was also able to replicate it like this:

Navigate to https://stackoverflow.com/site-analytics and stay on the history tab. Every pop up could work. Click on traffic sources, hover over `Top Ten Referring Sites` circle and then go back to history. Now neither the pop up for Traffic or Votes worked for me.

OS: Windows 10 Pro
Browser: Chrome 80.0.3987.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

**Feature request:**

Also I think the pop up is to far to the right, should show up closer to the mouse pointer. When looking at data points at the end of the diagram the pop up is far off as seen below.

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/site-analytics

Comment: it works for me. I'm on Chrome, win10

Comment: @rene Works for me now as well, did not work 10 minutes ago.

Comment: Hmm, weird. I did had a glitch on the site being off-line for a moment 20 minutes ago or so. Maybe that was somehow related.

Comment: @rene Perhaps - nice that it is working again though. Very weird that only `Traffic` would be affected and not the other diagrams. Looked at the `HTML` and nothing updated when looking at `Traffic`. Saw updates in `HTLM` for both `Posts` and `Votes`.

Comment: @rene There is something wrong with the pop up I think. I was on the `history` tab and every pop up worked, clicked on `traffic sources`, hovered over `Top Ten Referring Sites` circle and then went back to `history`. Now neither the pop up for `Traffic` or `Votes` worked.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. That is super weird.

Comment: Any work on this happening? Tooltips are only displaying for top chart for me on Chrome Version 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)